# Не находит элемент через Selenium при запуске через threading

Tags: python, selenium, threading

У меня есть код, который при нажатии на кнопку заходит на сайт и там регистрирует почту, но не в этом суть. При обычном запуске, а именно через command=startreg всё отлично, не считая того, что программа зависает до окончания завершения функции, поэтому я использую threading, но при запуске через него не находятся элементы.

Функция запускается через другую функцию, т.к. нужно будет ещё кое-что туда добавить:

```
def startreg():
mail_tm()
```

Вот код кнопки:

```
start = Button(window, text="Запустить", font=("Lucida Console", fontsizeHding), fg="#5B04BC", bg="#1d1d1d", borderwidth=0, activebackground="#5B04BC", command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=startreg, daemon=True).start())
```

Вот код функции:

```
def mail_tm():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
    browser.get('https://mail.tm/ru/')
    colvo = format(kolvo.get())
    al = 0
    while al < int(colvo): #Здесь ставим число аккаунтов
        try:
            time.sleep(0.8)
            browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="accounts-menu"]').click()
            time.sleep(0.1)
            mail = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="accounts-list"]/div/div[1]/p[2]').text
            passw = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="accounts-list"]/div/div[1]/p[3]/span').text
            browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="accounts-list"]/div/div[7]/a').click()
            if mail == "":
                print("не получил почту")
            else:
                cur.execute(f'INSERT INTO mailtm(mail, password) VALUES ("{mail}", "{passw}")')
                con.commit()
                print('Удачно!')
                al=al+1
                print(al)
        except:
            print('Ошибка!')
            browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="accounts-list"]/div/div[7]/a').click()
    browser.close()
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Была похожая проблема у моего парсера.
Попробуй использовать javascript.В моем случае это сработало.`

```
mail = driver.execute_script("""
                 let mail = document.querySelector('.имя-класса);
                 return mail
             """)
```